# Need help adding tags [#24] Sakuras, Tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

The full code for the theme is [here](http://pastebin.com/hJJfYvit) and a preview is located [here](http://24sakuras.tumblr.com/). They show on the permalink page but not the theme's front page.

I've tried to theme it using various codes, including one by the theme maker, but with no real success! Not overly picky about how the tags appear, though being at the bottom of the post in some fashion would be preferable.

Comment: This question isn't going to be very helpful for future readers. Presumably those links won't work forever and, once they stop working, all of the salient data is gone. One of the driving purposes of Stack Exchange is to act as a repository of knowledge. More information here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Cut all of line 640 (from the "full code" link you provided) and paste it after line 632, or anywhere before `{/block:IndexPage}` (which is on line 663).

If you examine the surrounding code, you can see `{block:PermalinkPage}` few lines above where the tags were originally, which means the `{block:HasTags}` (if it has tags) and subsequent children `{block:Tags}` (each tag) only render on the permalink page.

If you move all of line 640 into `{block:IndexPage}`, they will display on the index page instead.

[Tumblr's documentation covers all of this, if you're really interested](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes). I hope I've been helpful to you :)